# Cannot login at hvc0

Tags: debian, xen, login

Our LDAP server recently crashed and now we are facing problems reaching some of our servers.

We have a Xen guest for which the login does no longer work. In the logs, the following error appears.

```
FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/hvc0' FOR 'root'
```

Here's a list of what I already tried (and did not resolve the problem).

- Resetting the root password (mounting to host, chroot and passwd, usual stuff...)
- Adding a new local account with root privileges (edited the sudoers file)
- Access through SSH...

All is broken. There is a MySQL server that is failing on that vm and I would really like to fix it. The vserver runs debian squeeze and hvc0 is listed in /etc/securetty.

I'm out of options... All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PAM configuration may be wrong. Your configuration should be something like this:

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so
auth required pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth required pam_permit.so


account [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so
account required pam_ldap.so
account required pam_permit.so
```

With those lines, local files are checked before LDAP.

Comment: It was indeed a PAM issue. replaced the pam.d directory with the contents of a freshly installed server et voila, I'm in! We will configure it for LDAP once the LDAP is up again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you face two distinct configuration options that forbids root logins. One is that root login will be allowed (by /sbin/login or PAM configuration) if there is an entry in `/etc/securetty` file for hvc0 device. Other is that sshd by default forbids login directly to root account.

You should add `hvc0` line/item to `/etc/securetty` file.